# XSLT Advice: making sure numbers are ## and removing unnecessary zeros

Tags: xml, xslt

I was hoping I could get some advice. I am a bit new to xslt and trying to make my raw xml into a .csv. I have managed it, but the scenarios have now changed and people want different things. So...

My first question:

I have a requirement for dates and times to be 01, 02 etc.

Currently the way the date is outputted is 9 when I need it to be 09. Below is my xslt (and apologies for it being a bit ugly...:)

```
<xsl:value-of select="@day"/>
```

I would need to get the same rule for @month, as I need to have the same ## format for that.

I know most would say use copy, but for this purpose I have had to use value of. Below is the raw xml I am trying to convert:

```
 <ESP_DATE
 date="2019-10-09"
 dateindays="43380"
 day="9"
 dayname="Wednesday"
 month="10"
 monthname="October"
 productionweeknumber="41"
 weekNumberYear="2019"
 weekdaynumber="3"
 weeknumber="41"
 year="2019"/>
```

I have tried using format-number and number, both with no luck (NaN).

My second question is not simpler. We have a time duration where I need to have HH and MM, raw xml below:

```
<duration>
<ESP_TIMEDURATION duration="55:00.000"/>
 </duration>
```

Here I tried to use concat, number and format-number to strip it out to have just HH and MM, so this would be 00:55. However, every time I do it I get the famous NaN.

Any help, pointers or links would be...greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Anne

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Also clarify  if the input duration can have more than 59 minutes.

Comment: Please, always, say which XSLT version you are using. From XSLT 2.0 onwards this kind of thing is really simple, so I guess you are probably still using an old XSLT 1.0 processor?

Comment: Hi Michael and Michael,

Understood and apologies. I am using xslt 1.0 progressor. We do have access to xslt 2.0, but witht he system we are using I have been asked to use 1.0...

Apologies,
Anne

Comment: @AnneS Are your questions not answered?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Questions are answered! I'll figure out how to close down this thread, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your 1st question, try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(@day, '00')"/>
```

You need to be in the context of `ESP_DATE` for this.

Comment: Hi Michael,

This is brilliant, I got it working! Thank you so much for the assistance. And apologies for the bad query writing!

Cheers,
Anne

Comment: I don't think I downvoted it...I wouldn't have, it helped me so much to get me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

For your 2nd question, consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<duration>
    <ESP_TIMEDURATION duration="124:30.132"/>
</duration>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="duration">
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="substring-before(ESP_TIMEDURATION/@duration, ':')" />
    <xsl:variable name="s" select="substring-after(ESP_TIMEDURATION/@duration, ':')" />
    <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="$m + round($s div 60)" />
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($minutes div 60), '00')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($minutes mod 60, ':00')"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<result>02:05</result>
```

Comment: Hi Michael,

Thank you for this! It took me awhile to get my head around but it did work in the end. I really appreciate the help and I have learned a lot! Never thought of using variables in this context.

Many thanks,
Anne